# Set value of hidden element in View and send it to component Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

Let's say I have an object, I'm reading the object properties in my view.
There is a property of the object called `role`, and I want to send that value from my view to my component, I will need to do some work with that value in my component...

This is my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class Globals {
    role: string = 'test role';
}
```

And this is my component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'    
import { Globals } from './globals'

@Component({
    selector: 'component2',
    template: `
    <div>          
<input [(ngModel)]="role"/>
      <button (click)="changedRole()">apply</button>
    </div>`
})
export class Component2 {
    private role: string;

    constructor(private globals: Globals) {
        this.role = globals.role;
    }

    private changedRole() {
        this.globals.role = this.role;
    }
}
```

Now, there are some things, I'm not interested in display the `role` value, so it would be better I guess in a hidden input, I've read that ngModel doesn't work with hidden fields, because it's goal is two-way databinding, and in this case I just want to set the value of the input(or any type of tag) with the `role` value of the object, and send it to the component, I've read that in angular 1 exists ng-value, for only one way data-binding from the view to the component. I'm working with angular 4 and I don't know to deal with this, I've tried something like this: `<input [(ngModel)]="role" value="{{myobject.role}}"/>` but of course it doesn't works with `ngModel` how can I send an object's property value from the view to the component?

Comment: Why do you want to put in a hidden input ? You always can get the value using this.globals.role

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `[value]` to bind the value

```
<input  [value]="role" type="hidden" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, reading more, inspired by your answers I found a nice video in pluralsight about databinding from view to component. I ended up doing this in my html:

```
 <a (click)="select(person.role)">{{person.Title}}</a>
```

And in my component I just added this method:

```
select(role: string) {
        console.log('the role selected was: ' + role);
    }
```

It worked.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not quite sure I understand what you're trying to do but you can use the event binding called

```
<input (change)="role = $event.value" [value]="role" />
```